# Java many threads to many threads relation

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, gateway

I have a service that gets requests from many clients and after some processing sends a response to the clients. I use a ThreadPoolExecutor (threadExecuterClient) to handle client requests and put them in a BlockingQueue (requestQueue). Many clients can send concurrent requests. I have another ThreadPoolExecutor (threadExecuterServer) that processes requests in requestQueue. This processing is basically consists of send that request to a server and get response. After processing, I need to send that response to the client which has made that request. I am having difficulties to track which client has made which request. I basically need to find a way to map the client request to the result of processing. The service will be like a gateway.

Any idea to handle this issue is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can atttach client ID with each request..and that request is recieved as it is to threadExecuterServer .. While executing the request , the request could be seggregated to get the actual request made by client.. and after request is processed reattach the client ID to the reponse code.. IMO

Comment: Sorry but your're looking for a way of tracking the jobs ? A simple logger that states the request ID for each performed processing ( request acceptation, processing via gateway, response sending ) is not enough ?

Comment: @VishalK My first intuition was like yours. However, it is too complex to handle requests by simply attaching an ID. Server threads are always alive and they can send requests as there are more requests in the queue without waiting the response for the previous requests. For the client threads, one thread is created per connection and the client can send multiple requests using same connection until client closes the connection. For the last part, I am not sure if it good to use one connection for multiple requests. I could use one unique connection per request.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your service accepts requests via HTTP ? Accept the request from your service and send back a [HTTP 202](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) response. This response means that the request was accepted for processing. When you send the response, send the **Location** header to tell the client which URL to invoke to ascertain the status of your request. The client can poll this URL for status and a result.

The URL should contain a unique ID for each request. Your server can track that and populate a response when it is ready.

Comment: Actually HTTP is not involved in this service. Client side, Gateway, and the server side are all java applications.

Comment: There is a socket connection between client and gateway, and between gateway and server.

Comment: In that case, keep a reference to that connection in your Task.  Return results as the final step of processing.

Comment: You can either return the results of your processing synchronously (which would not require a tracking ID) or return a tracking ID to the socket and ask the client to connect to another socket and pass the tracking ID to poll the result. The latter method will make sure that the socket does consume additional resources while the server is processing the request.